# qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: linux, display, xorg, centos-7, xvfb

Cannot get CutyCapt to work. I am running this on a CentOS 7 VM. I am running this directly on the command line and not using a script yet.

```
# echo $DISPLAY
:0

# CutyCapt --url=https://hostname/abc --out=test.jpg
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Have the same issue when I run it with `xvfb-run`

```
# xvfb-run --server-args="screen 0, 1920x1080x24" CutyCapt --url=https://hostname/abc --out=test.jpg
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :99
Could not connect to any X display.
/bin/xvfb-run: line 186: kill: (4853) - No such process
```

I enabled X11 Forwarding in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as well, but does not seemed to have helped.

```
# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep X11Forw
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
```

Any suggestions on how to get this going?

Comment: Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `X11Forwarding yes` with `ForwardX11 yes`.

Comment: This is wrong answer! You did not specify the reason why the solution is ForwardX11 yes